# How to select only these IDs which shows in table for the first time during last 30 days in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, time, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table in Oracle SQL presents ID of clients and date with time of their login to application:

```
ID | LOGGED
----------------
11 | 2021-09-10 12:55:13.278
11 | 2021-08-10 13:58:13.211
11 | 2021-02-11 12:22:13.364
22 | 2021-09-15 08:34:13.211
33 | 2021-04-02 14:21:13.272
```

How can I select only these IDs, which logged the first time during last 30 days ?
So as a result I need something like below:

```
ID
---
22
```

Because only ID 22 logged first time during last 30 days -> 2021-09-15 08:34:13.211
How can I do that in Oracle SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
    Select id from table where trunc(logged) 
    >= 
    Trunc(sysdate-30) group by id having count(*) =1
```

Or better condition is using min, max

```
     Select id from table where trunc(logged) 
    >= 
    Trunc(sysdate-30) group by id having min(logged) 
     =max(logged)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is ok? when we take min(logged) = max(logged) we will have ID which logged only one time in last 30 days, what in situation when in last 30 days ID logged a few times, in this way wil will not have min = max

Comment: Yes for valid entries unless some superman might log in multiple times at the same time